# Alamofire 5 get error code to check internet connection

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 5 for my network layer I have defined Network error as below.

I am checking `response.error.isNetworkError` I am getting always false because now I am getting code as 9 instead of -1099/

```
extension Error {
    var code: Int { return (self as NSError).code }
    var domain: String { return (self as NSError).domain }

    var isNetworkError: Bool {
        switch code {
        case NSURLErrorCannotFindHost,
             NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed,
             NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed,
             NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost,
             NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
            return true

        default:
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

possibly it will be helpful to somebody. With new Alamofire 5 AFError can be casted to NSError. So, if you simply need to get a code you can do this

```
if let nsError = error as NSError? {
    nsError.code
    ...
```

In case if you need to check internet connection. You can do check for some specific error type, for example:

```
if let afError = error?.asAFError {
    if afError.isSessionTaskError {
       ...
```

And finally, if you need to get URLError, which can be achieved from underlying error you should do something like this

```
if let afError = error?.asAFError {
    if let urlError = afError.underlyingError as! URLError?, urlError.code == URLError.notConnectedToInternet {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get Http Error Like This :

```
    guard let error = (response.error?.underlyingError as? URLError) else { return }
    
    switch error.code {
    case .timedOut:
    // Do SomeThing
    case .notConnectedToInternet:
    // Do SomeThing
    default:
        break
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(afError.underlyingError as? NSError)?.errorCode == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet
```

This should work